# Send file back after GET request Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mean-stack, multer

I am trying to build a REST API using a MEAN stack and I have encountered a problem. I am saving a .txt file sent in a POST request to the server and saving it using multer in an /uploads folder. I am then saving the req.file information in a collection on mongodb (path included).

The problem that I have now is that I want to be able to handle a GET request for that specific file with the ObjectId. However I want to be able to get the file from the file path and then send it to the user making the GET request.

Right now I am only returning the information corresponding to the ObjectId passed, not the file. How can I send back the whole .txt file back to the user?

```
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
try
{
    var id = new require('mongodb').ObjectID(req.params.id);
    console.log('Retrieving log: ' + id);

    db.collection('logs', function(err, collection) {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            collection.findOne({'_id':id}, function(err, item) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error finding log: ' + err);
                    res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
                } else {
                    console.log('' + item + ' found log');
                    console.log(item.path);
                    var file = __dirname + item.path;
                    res.download(file);
                    //res.send(item);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
catch (e)
{
    console.log('Id passed not correct');
    res.send({'error':'Id passed not correct'});
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I finally got the server to respond to the GET request.

I had to find the file path of the file that had been saved into the database.

```
collection.findOne({'_id':id}, function(err, item) {
                if (err) 
                {
                    console.log('Error finding log: ' + err);
                    res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
                }
                if (item)
                {
                    //Create the path of the file wanted
                    filepath = path.join(__dirname, "../uploads", path.normalize(item.filename));
                    //Send file with the joined file path
                    res.sendFile(filepath);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    console.log("Could not find entry");
                    res.send({'error':'No match found'});
                }
            });
```

This enabled me to send the file back by getting the full path of the file.